# Moving/Streaming data out of Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

What is the best way to moving/streaming data out of Google cloud storage? Also, Does Dataflow offer any feature to stream data from Google cloud storage to outside  GCP?

Answer (score 1):

The Best way to move data out of Google cloud storage is perhaps there gsutil tool or you can use the python and boto plugin that they provide for simplicity, You will find the details of this in this link.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming.
As for the second part of the question, Kafka can be connected to Cloud Dataflow as of now and I think you can use that to stream data out of GCP. Apache Beam supports KafkaIO as of 2016. I guess the below link would helo you a lot.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/09/apache-kafka-for-gcp-users-connectors-for-pubsub-dataflow-and-bigquery

https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/kafka

Comment: Can we use Spring application running in GCP to move data out of Google Cloud storage?

Comment: can you tell me what is spring application is doing..?

Comment: If I am correctly understanding your question a spring application can be deployed and be  expected to as it does in normal scenario in GCP. If you want to use it to bundle and use components of hadoop, then you can go for Cloud Dataproc and in any other case it can be deployed in a compute instance and expect the same result as we do in any other distributed environment.

Comment: Usecase - 1 - I am trying to use Cloud Data flow to stream data from Pub-Sub and then use JDBCIO to write data to an on-prem DB or TextIO to write file to on-prem server. Please let me know if it is doable?

Comment: yes it is very much doable. you will need the google cloud SDK on the on-prem cluster.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate a bit? Say with the google cloud SDK on the on-prem cluster, would just configuring the Google cloud Dataflow pipeline to write to the on-prem host would work? Just checking if any other settings are required while implementing.

Comment: No other setting would be required other than installing the Google Cloud SDK. You should be able  to do what you are aiming for. Let me know if there are any other issues.

Comment: I tried a simple test to write to from Google Cloud storage to my Local machine. I used a DirectPipelineRunner. The dataflow job ran and succeeded. But i don't see the file created in my local machine. Sample command below: gcloud dataflow jobs run sampleJobname1 --gcs-location gs://bucket/templatename1 --parameters inputFilePattern=gs://samplegcsbucket/abc/*,outputLocation=C:\data\gcp\outer,runner=DirectPipelineRunner

Comment: Can you specify the --tempLocation/--gcpTempLocation with the command and try again.